# Acerca de sitemap dinámico

Tags: .htaccess, sitemap

Tengo alguna duda sobre los sitemaps dinámicos. He creado un fichero `sitemap.php` en la raíz del proyecto.

Y en htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap\.php [L]
```

Ese código lo he cogido de tutoriales que he visto por internet, pero no entiendo por qué tiene esa estructura, si lo tengo en la raíz del proyecto, ¿no debería ser algo así?

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml sitemap.php [L]
```

Que por otra parte, cuando los buscadores piden el sitemap, ¿buscan en sitemap.xml y es cuando se le re-dirige a sitemap.php?

No sé cómo puedo comprobar si el sitemap generado con PHP es correcto, en google sólo deja subir .xml.

Answer (score 0):

El punto en expresiones regex tiene un significado especial, por lo que si quieres usarlo como lo que es, **debes *escaparlo***, es decir, marcarlo para que sea identificado como un carácter y no como un signo especial.

#### Respuestas relacionadas

**Cómo encuentran los buscadores los sitemaps**
Puedes establecer la dirección del sitemap en el archivo `robots.txt`, con una línea como esta:

```
Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap.xml
```

**Como validar un sitemap**
Para asegurar que un sitemap sea correcto debes asegurar que:

- Esté bien formado, es decir, que todas las etiquetas estén cerradas correctamente y los textos entre comillas, etc.
- Sea válido, es decir, que los elementos que forman el esquema estén presentes en el lugar correcto.

Hay muchas herramientas para validar, en línea, puedes probar la de [Yandex](https://webmaster.yandex.com/tools/sitemap/), un buscador ruso.

> El [protocolo Sitemap](https://www.sitemaps.org/es/protocol.html#) no especifica la extensión del archivo, pero también podrías pegar el contenido para validarlo.

#### Enlaces útiles

- El protocolo sitemap: https://www.sitemaps.org/es/protocol.html
- Herramientas de validación: https://www.w3.org/XML/Schema#Tools
- El esquema DTD de sitemaps: http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd
- Directrices de Google sobre los sitemaps: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=es&ref_topic=4581190

Comment: Gracias, le estoy echando un vistazo, aunque no acabo de tener claro cómo proceder. Por otra parte, ¿es normal que se vea como si fuese en una linea? https://s15.postimg.org/4y2h5d58r/Captura_de_pantalla_2017-06-12_a_las_23.22.36.png Siempre que me da algún error me pone linea 1 columna XX, encontrar el error ahí es horrible.

Comment: @JetLagFox los sitemaps no son hechos para consumo humano. Los espacios y saltos de línea solo son adornos en un sitemap que no necesita un analizador, además ahorran espacio y ancho de banda. No sé a que te refieres con _"como proceder"_, si tienes un problema con tu sitemap, deberías hacer una pregunta nueva detallándolo y de ser posible incluye un __[mcve]__.

Comment: Me refiero a que no me acaba de quedar claro si lo tengo que hacer a través de htaccess, de robots.txt o es indiferente. Y si es por htaccess, que es como lo estoy intentando hacer, si el código sería correcto si el fichero está en la raíz del proyecto.

Comment: En el `.htaccess` haces una cosa (la reescritura), en `robots.txt` haces otra (notificar a los buscadores). Es __una costumbre__ colocar el archivo en la raíz del sitio, pero dado que indicas la URI completa en el archivo `robots.txt`, donde lo pongas no es tan importante.

Comment: He realizado los pasos pero aunque el sitemap se me genera bien, me da un problema con Google, y es que lo reconoce como HTML. En `robots.txt` concretamente estoy usando la siguiente línea: `Sitemap: http://www.LaXtore.com/sitemap.xml` y en htaccess `RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]`

Comment: Ese es otro problema. Te recomiendo hacer otra pregunta donde incluyas la información sobre como lo generas, de ser posible con un [mcve].